How to make Visual Studio 2022 use the include paths you configure?
I created a VS2022 project, and it setup a directory structure with a ./src and a ./src/include subdirectory.
I want to put my header files in the include directory and my .cpp in the src directory.
When I do this, none of the header files are found.

Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'application.h': No such file or
directory C:\Users<username>\src\project1\project1.vcxproj   C:> \Users\\src\project1\src\application.cpp 2

This error makes no sense.   It has nothing to do with header files (is it trying to say the search for the include file was prompted by those other two files?  what?), and the files it says are not there are in fact actually there.
I've tried changing the AdditionalIncludeDirectories to  %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);include;. per some other threads' suggestion, for both Release and Debug, and this did not help.
When I view the files in Explorer, they are there and readable.  When I view them in the Folder view in the IDE, they are there and readable (I can open them in the IDE).  When I change #include "file.h" to #include "include/file.h", it works (edit:  correction - it doesn't work.  "Intellisense" is finding the headers this way but not the actual build)
When I set the output stream options to "Detailed" so I can see the cl.exe command line, there is no /I option being generated whatsoever.
What is the correct way to get this frustrating mess of an IDE to actually look at the include file settings and use /I to find the files?

Please show a [mre], screenshots and full compiler output might help

Close voter, notice the close criteria you suggested was "issue was resolved in a way that is not likely to be useful for readers".    The issue was not resolved.

@AlanBirtles  Literally I only installed VS2022, created a new project, put a single include file and a single source file, and tried to compile, using the directories I indicate above.  I also deleted the project and reproduced the issue.   There are also about 1,000 threads on various sites in the past decade or so with the same issue.  I'll add screenshots (I would have originally, but had a question on here closed because I included screen shots once...)

Screenshots of code and other text are frowned upon but screenshots off things like ide settings are sometimes helpful

@BadZen - If the header is part of the project, you should add it to the Solution Explorer in the IDE. It is not an "Additional" include, but a primary one.

Right on guys, this question is definitely not about programming...  =/

"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" are on topic.   But by all means continue to try and censor any problems that anyone has because it's software made by your employer.

@BoP - The headers in question are absolutely added to the project.  (they have the normal icon, not the red x circle, and their "Included In Project" property is "True")

Note that the "does not appear to be about programming" is a generic message when people vote for different close reasons, the reason for closing is that this isn't a problem we can solve without a [mre]

I have the same or similar issue. Confusing to say the least. I don't get why there is so much concern over closing the issue rather than offering a solution. - now SO purist fight over my comment. I still would like to know the answer.

Larry - If it helps this looks like it was a bug that was a regression in the early releases of 17.10 - updating to 17.10.5 seems to have fixed it!   (They're not "SO purists", they're an army of MS "enthusiasts", cultists, and employees, you will continue to encounter them...)


In the solution explorer window make your project the startup project.
Right click on the project and select Properties.
Expand the C/C++ option.
Select General.
Put the path to your includes on the front of the line, and put a semicolon between that and the additional include directories entry.
Click OK, and rebuild your project.
You should be good to go.


I followed these steps when I set up the project.  The problem occures after doing all of this.   The issue seems to be a defect in a specific version of VS, upgrading fixed it.
